# Any way to make this recursive function better/faster?

Tags: c#, recursion

Is there anything that can be done differently for this function?  Any way to make it faster?

```
public List<Channel> ChildrenOf(Channel startingChannel)
{
    List<Channel> result = new List<Channel>();

    foreach (Channel child in startingChannel.Children)
    {
        result.Add(child);
        result.AddRange(ChildrenOf(child));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like that's it. But maybe someone else has some other ideas.

Comment: Your approach has a problem with deeply nested lists. Let's say you have N items at a nesting depth D. Then each item will be copied D times -> O(N*D) time.
The "yield return" answer has a similar issue: for each item, it has to execute D 'yield return' statements.
Guffa's answer doesn't have this problem and will run in O(N) time.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with tail recursion? HRMMM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd separate iteration and adding items to a list:

```
public IEnumerable<Channel> ChildrenOf(Channel root)
{
    yield return root;
    foreach(var c in root.Children)
       foreach(var cc in ChildrenOf(c))
          yield return cc;
}
```

Comment: does this make it better/faster? How does the IL compare?

Comment: Almost there, dont forget to yield back first level childs though

Comment: @luketorjussen: This method is faster since it doesn't require any allocations on the heap and hence, therefore no deallocations. be aware though that since the data is not cached in a list, manipulation is not possible and multiple iterations will execute the function multiple times

Comment: @Polity: Actually, each "foreach" loop will create an enumerator object which is still an allocation on the heap (the inner loop creates an enumerator for each iteration of the outer loop).

Comment: @BrianReichle - That depends, if root.Children is a BCL .NET collection like a list or Array, it will allocate on the stack

Comment: @Polity, I would not be surprised if a foreach loop over an array was optimised to a for loop by the compiler (and hence be on the stack) but the result of the 'ChildrenOf' method in the inner loop is not such a class :)

Comment: @BrianReichle - Damn! your right! I was completely looking beyond your point, thank you for having the patience to shake me awake!

Comment: i am really interested in your solution, but it returns also the root channel, trying to remove the 'yield return root;' has caused it to not return ANY child channels... can you explain why?

Comment: @Dementic: It doesn't return anything because currently, each element is responsible for returning itself -- and that's the statement that does it.  What you could do is add `yield return c;` to the outer foreach (and of course, add braces around the two statements!).

Comment: k, got it. the function name should be changed to ChildrenOfAndParent :) thx cHao and Anton

Comment: Or move the `yield return root;` to inside the first for and change it to `yield return c;`, I guess?

Comment: You still end up with it on the heap since using "yield return" transforms your method into a class with fields for your local variables.

Comment: You should be careful to avoid `yield return` in recursive functions, the memory usage scales explosively. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30300257/284795 . Thus Guffa's and Lippert's solutions are preferable.

Answer (score 41):

Just to round out the other answers: I would be inclined to write your solution like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstTreeTraversal<T>(T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)      
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while(stack.Count != 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        // If you don't care about maintaining child order then remove the Reverse.
        foreach(var child in children(current).Reverse())
            stack.Push(child);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

And now to achieve your aim, you just say:

```
    static List<Channel> AllChildren(Channel start)
    {
        return DepthFirstTreeTraversal(start, c=>c.Children).ToList();
    }
```

Now you have a more general-purpose tool that you can use to get a depth-first traversal of *any* tree structure, not just your particular structure.

Another nice feature of my solution is that *it uses a fixed amount of call stack space*. Even if your hierarchy is twenty thousand deep, you never run out of stack space because the method is not recursive to begin with. All the information that would be needed for recursion is stored on the "stack" data structure instead of in activation records on the real call stack.

Comment: Damn.  And here I was, coming to answer this with just such a generic stack... :)

Comment: +1 for populating a List using this traversal extension.  I make a C# Extension for the traversal method and use it on a bunch of stuff. I find it much easier to understand than using a recursive method.

Comment: Micro-optimisation: I would put the `yield` before the `foreach`, to save some cycles and memory in case the iteration of the enumerator is stopped midway.

Answer (score 16):

Put the recursive part in a private method, so that you can add the items directly to the list instead of creating intermediate lists:

```
public List<Channel> ChildrenOf(Channel startingChannel) {
  List<Channel> result = new List<Channel>();
  AddChildren(startingChannel, result);
  return result;
}

private void AddChildren(Channel channel, List<Channel> list) {
  foreach (Channel child in channel.Children) {
    list.Add(child);
    AddChildren(child, list);
  }
}
```

(This is basically the same principle as Polity suggested, only it's implemented in two methods so that you don't have to create an empty list to call it.)

Answer (score 11):

Share your result list would be one way of preventing allocations and esspecially collections to happen

```
 public List<Channel> ChildrenOf(Channel startingChannel, List<Channel> result) 
    { 
        foreach (Channel child in startingChannel.Children) 
        { 
            result.Add(child);

            // this will internally add to result
            ChildrenOf(child, result);
        } 

        return result; 
    }
```